# VSTS : In task we have got action button in which there is create branch how does it work..?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have used VSTS (Azure DevOps) for task assignment in my team.

When I create a task, in task window to the very right I can see action option with three dots, by clicking on that I can see there is option new branch I believe that means to create a new branch for that task. but I don't know how it works because whenever I click on it nothing happens. I use VSTS source control as my central repository.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work because you use TFVC as source control and not Git.

You can create only a Git branch and not TFVC branch (also you can link only a Git branch to work item).

[image]

So why the option is visible? because sometimes you can create a branch even if your project is using TFVC - you would also need to have at least one Git repo.